# get tabId from Puppeteer when new tab is created

Tags: puppeteer

I'm testing a Chrome extensions and in order to setup everything correctly I would like to know the tabId when a new tab is created

```
 const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ ... });

 const appPage = await browser.newPage();
 await appPage.goto(appUrl, { waitUntil: 'load' });

 // TAB ID??????
```

I checked the [documentation](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v13.7.0&show=api-class-page) of the Page object but there is nothing about a tabId. So my question is, is it possible to extract a tabId with Puppereer?

Comment: What's a tab id exactly and why do you need it? What functionality/behavior are you trying to implement that the page's object reference isn't good enough as an id, or assigning your own isn't sufficient?

Comment: Each tab has an id, which is used by the chrome extension for sending messages to the correct tab